# Random errors when matching strings

Tags: karate, string-matching

Usually matching works just fine but I've had weird random matching errors recently :

```
$.userInfo | not equal | match failed for name: 'phone' (MAP:MAP)
{"givenName":"##string","familyName":"##string","phone":"##string"}
{"givenName":"Andreas","familyName":"Conroy","phone":"+19515554384"}

$.userInfo.phone | not equal (STRING:STRING)
'##string'
'+19515554384'
```

How is '+19515554384' not a string ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have your "expected" vs "actual" data mixed up. Here below are 2 lines you can cut and paste and verify that it works:

```
* def response = {"givenName":"Andreas","familyName":"Conroy","phone":"+19515554384"}
* match response == {"givenName":"##string","familyName":"##string","phone":"##string"}
```

Comment: OK that was it ... reversed actual/expected. Thanks